# The data in the list disappear after restarting the app

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, sharedpreferences, dart-pub

[image]
I update the task status to true and show it on another page with ListView.builder when I update the status and go to the author page I find it there but when I restart the app I don't see it anymore while using this Debug line `print('Task index:  {task.status}');` I find after restarting the app the status turns to false can anyone help

i use cubit in this project so i don't know if I should warp this widget with BlocProvider or BlocBuilder and I use hive for the database i update the database with this founction

```
updateBox(int index, bool newStatus) async {
    try {
      emit(DoneNotificationLoding());
      tasksList![index].status = newStatus;
      mybox!.put('tasks', tasksList);
      print(tasksList);
      emit(DoneNotificationSuccess());
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error :  ${e}');
      emit(DoneNotificationError());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah cause you but be initialising the status with false and when the app restarted it start execution from the main and all your data will be re initialised, So for that you need to use something like `SharedPreference` that will save your state through out the application.

Comment: Remember that not everyone can see the images, so put the code as formatted text. Also, [hive] is for _Apache Hive_: If you hover the pointer over the tag, you will see that the tag to use instead is [flutter-hive]. Please [edit] your question to improve it.